# Regex with two patterns

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement where in I want to get two different items form one long string.
I have got below program where in I get required items when I do group(1) and group(6).
But I want to get it in group(1) and group(2).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExample {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String somepattern = "((123|456)-(0|1)-((\\d-?){8})-\\d{1})/(\\d{2})";


   String str = "/somethingwaste/123-0-1234-5678-9/10"; 
   Matcher p = Pattern.compile(somepattern).matcher(str);
    while (p.find()) {
    System.out.println(p.group(1));
    System.out.println(p.group(6));
   }
```

Any pointers directions appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: The magic word is `non-capturing group`. Please look it up in the regex docs.

Comment: If you have a problem and decide to solve it with a regex, then you have two problems =)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
String somepattern = "((?:123|456)-[01]-(?:\\d-?){8}-\\d)/(\\d{2})";
```

The `?:` makes a `()` non-capturing.

Comment: This is a better answer in my opinion, since it removes the redundancy in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the groups you don't want to keep `non-capturing` using `?:`:

```
String somepattern = "((?:123|456)-[01]-(?:\\d-?){8}-\\d)/(\\d{2})";
String str = "/somethingwaste/123-0-1234-5678-9/10";
Matcher p = Pattern.compile(somepattern).matcher(str);
while (p.find()) {
    System.out.println(p.group(1));
    System.out.println(p.group(2));
}
```